How to validate within the security rules if the writing you want to do was requested from a transaction
I have two collections named "usuarios" and "juegos". I am performing a transaction where a document is added to the "usuarios" collection and another document is added to the "juegos" collection. How can I validate in the security rules that, simultaneously with a write operation in the "usuarios" collection, a write operation is also taking place in the "juegos" collection due to the transaction?

You need to define what the other document written to "juegos" looks like in terms of logic that can be expressed by security rules.  You haven't described that logic in your question.  You can't just write a rule that checks for "a write operation".  You have be able to express specifically which document was written using its unique id (and maybe also check its contents after you read it in the transaction).  See the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents

There's no way to specifically check for a transaction, nor should you need that. Wanting it sounds like a XY problem to me.
Consider what you actually want to accomplish with the check. For example, if you want to test whether another document exists/was modified by the current write, you can use existsAfter/getAfter for that. For more on those, see the last paragraph in the documentation on accessing other documents:

For writes, you can use the getAfter() function to access the state of a document after a transaction or batch of writes completes but before the transaction or batch commits. Like get(), the getAfter() function takes a fully specified document path. You can use getAfter() to define sets of writes that must take place together as a transaction or batch.


sorry for that, I already edited my question

Yup, for that use-case getAfter and existsAfter are the right approach.

The bad thing is that these reads made by getAfter are charged. It would be good if there was another way to check if the writing that is currently being done is being done from a transaction and the information is contained in the request and that says what other writes are being done in the transaction.
Something like "request.transaction != null && request.transaction.hasOnly("users", "games");

I can only explain how the system works, and how you can implement the use-case. If you'd like the system to function differently, I recommend filing a feature request.
